# concatening PHP variable and strings inside double quotes for onclick event

Tags: javascript, php, html

The button when pressed call a function that needs the sn value, but the code below fails with the Chrome debug message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Telephony is not defined

Telephony is one of the service names.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>someTitle</title>
<script>
function myF(varname) {
    //I'll do here some other task with varname
    console.log(varname);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<pre>
<?php
$sn='noname';
//here, the code to connect and select DB
while ($reg=mysql_fetch_array($registers))

{
 echo "Service Name: ".$reg['sname']."<br>";
 $sn = $reg['sname'];

 echo "<button onclick=\"myF($sn)\">Vote</button>";
 echo "<hr>";
}

mysql_close($conexion);
?>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible a simple solution? My PHP server has PHP5

Comment: Inspect the button element does generated correctly in browser? like `<button onclick="myF('abcd')">Vote</button>`

Comment: You sure `$sn` is being set in your echo ?

Comment: @Ranjith aha, your suggestion works, so the question is how convert the value of $sn in string ?

Comment: @Darren echo $ng is displayed correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need double quotes?

```
echo "<button onclick=\"myF($sn)\">Vote</button>";
```

Do this instead:

```
echo '<button onclick="myF(\''. $sn . '\')">Vote</button>';
```

Or perhaps do it with [`sprintf`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) like this:

```
echo sprintf("<button onclick=\"myF('%s')\">Vote</button>", $sn);
```

Comment: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: cosonle show $sn, inspecting debuger it is shown <button onclick="myF('$sn')">

Comment: damn man, it worked !, can you suggest me a good book or link to learn this matter, usually  I have troubles with strings concatenation in javascript and php, especially when it is needed to concat strings and variables inside strings like in this case, thanks anyway I will mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

1. Assume your variable $sn is "Stack". Hence $sn is a string you need to pass this variable
   as a string.
2. So rewrite myF($sn) as myF("'".$sn."'").
3. When yu inspect the button you can see myF('Stack').
4. then in javascript you can avoid the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your concatenation need to change like this,

```
echo '<button onclick="myF("'.$sn.'")">Vote</button>';
```

Comment: Sorry, Unexpected token ILLEGAL Unexpected token ILLEGAL when pressed

Comment: my friend, when button is pressed this message is shown *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } *

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
 echo "<button onclick=\"myF('$sn')\">Vote</button>";
```

I tried out a simple test case, without any MySQL. You can find the code I used below:

```
<?php
    $sn='noname';
    $registers = array(array('sname' => 'apple'), array('sname' => 'banana'), array('sname' => 'woodapple')); // Dummy "MySQL" Fetch Array (this might differ from what your 'while' loop receives)
    foreach ($registers as $reg){ // In your case, a 'while' loop works.
     echo "Service Name: ".$reg['sname']."<br>";
     $sn = $reg['sname'];
     echo "<button onclick=\"myF('$sn')\">Vote</button>"; // Added Quotes.
     echo "<hr>";
    }
?>
```

HINT: Please refrain from using mysql_* functions! They are deprecated!

Answer (score -1):

I think that when you are passing the PHP variable as an argument in to the `onclick` event of button for calling `javascript function`, you string breaks because it is not quoted. So it needs to be quoted. I have edited the code line where you need to edit you code. So try like:

```
...
......
........
........
echo "<button onclick=\"myF(&quot;$sn&quot;)\">Vote</button>";
.......
......
....
```

Comment: no error in Chrome debug but nothing is shown when press the button, also inspecting the function it is seen *console.log(varname);*

Comment: What is there in $sn ? Give me the output !

Comment: the $sn contains the text value from DB, I've checked this by doing echo $sn but apparently your echo doesn't call the function, so nothing is shown when the button is pressed.